# Why the services do not start at installation?

Tags: upstart, services, software-installation, sysv

I've seen this sometime now, but not finding anything in the ubuntu man about this peculiar `policy-rc.d` binary that prevents services from being started/restarted/stopped when called by dpkg/apt, so I would like to know what is the reason of this.

```
Setting up lxc (0.9.0-0ubuntu3.6) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

Apparently, no package owns this binary:

```
dpkg -S /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This "script" is included in the `sysv-rc` package. This is part of a Debian policy which allows sysadmins to control what services starts/restarts/stops whenever they install/upgrade/uninstall packages:

> ## POLICY-RC.D   Policy layer (/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d) interface:
>
> Most Debian systems will not have this script as the need for a policy
>   layer is not very common. Most people using chroot jails just need an
>   one-line script which returns an exit status of 101 as the jailed
>   /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d script.
>
> The /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d file *must* be managed through the
>   alternatives system (/usr/sbin/update-alternatives) by any packages
>   providing it.
>
> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d [options]   []
>
> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d [options] --list  [...]

([Source](http://people.debian.org/~hmh/invokerc.d-policyrc.d-specification.txt))

So, what happens here? Well, whenever this script is present it will return a code which states the current policy of the local system (which is by default `101` = action forbidden by policy). If you want to change the policy, just modify the file as root to any of this values:

```
  0 - action allowed
  1 - unknown action (therefore, undefined policy)
 100 - unknown initscript id
 101 - action forbidden by policy
 102 - subsystem error
 103 - syntax error
 104 - [reserved]
 105 - behaviour uncertain, policy undefined.
 106 - action not allowed. Use the returned fallback actions
       (which are implied to be "allowed") instead.
```

The script is still a place holder, but when completed all these values could be returned. If you want to allow any change just change `exit 101` for `exit 0` and done. Whenever you install/remove/upgrade a service these will be (re)started/stopped.

Comment: Docker images has a fixed `exit 101` ```# For most Docker users, "apt-get install" only happens during "docker build",
# where starting services doesn't work and often fails in humorous ways. This
# prevents those failures by stopping the services from attempting to start.```

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie please can you elaborate? I am having this issue when building a docker image and I seem to be unable to fix it

Comment: possible solution: http://www.monblocnotes.com/node/2057

Comment: @JonnyFlowers He refers to [these lines, in docker's source](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L40)

Comment: @Bigood: the line number changed in the recent `master` branch. Here is [a permalink to the lines in docker's source(https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v17.05.0-ce/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L63).