# How to remove a package providing a service without stopping the service?

Tags: uninstall, services

I currently have the [uwsgi [image: Install uwsgi]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/uwsgi) package installed. I would like to remove the package but leave the current uWSGI instances running. Is this possible?

*(Yes, I do realize the service will only continue running until it is stopped or the server restarts.)*

Comment: Did you try modifying the pre/post rm scripts to remove commands stopping the service?

Comment: Say, which method did you use, finally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `prerm` of `uwsgi` script contains this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/uwsgi" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/uwsgi.conf" ]; then
    invoke-rc.d uwsgi stop || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

You have a few options:

### Edit the `prerm` script.

The script is usually located at `/var/lib/dpkg/uwsgi.prerm`.
Do:

```
sudo sed -i '/invoke-rc.d/ s/^/#/' /var/lib/dpkg/uwsgi.prerm
```

to comment out the command that stops the service.

### Use the conditions in the script to your advantage

Either:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/uwsgi
```

since the script checks for execute permissions of this script,

Or:

```
mv /etc/init/uwsgi.conf /etc/init/uwsgi.conf.bak
```

since the script checks for existence of this Upstart service file.

According to the [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/uwsgi/filelist), the package has `/etc/init.d/uwsgi` and not the Upstart script.

### (Mis)Use `policy-rc.d`

`invoke-rc.d` is controlled by [`policy-rc.d`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365911/why-the-services-do-not-start-at-installation). However, using it directly has a problem. The `prerm` script is has `exit $?`, and `dpkg` doesn't like non-zero exit codes. Hence, this will still require changing the `prerm` script:

```
echo 'exit 101' > /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d
chmod +x /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d
sed 's/exit/echo/' -i /var/lib/dpkg/uwsgi.prerm
```

### Why did I even answer?

There are some brilliant answers already available: [Install packages without starting background processes and services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74061/install-packages-without-starting-background-processes-and-services) (possibly with some slight adaptation required).

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep the package installed until shutdown. That will accomplish relatively the same thing.

Do this by running this command as root:

```
echo "sudo apt-get remove uwsgi" > /etc/rc6.d/K99_script
```

followed by:

```
chmod +x K99_script
```

When you shutdown, the package will automagically be uninstalled.

Note, though, that after your system comes back up, you should delete the K99 script file.

Comment: Thanks but I need to have the package removed before shutdown since I'm installing the uWSGI package from PIP and some of the files will likely conflict.

Comment: @NathanOsman uWSGI might depend on NTLM (not loaded to memory) files. Keeping the service running might cause problems. Why can't you just uninstall one and install the other?

Comment: I was trying to avoid downtime since I only had a single server at the time I originally asked this question (we have two now).

Comment: @NathanOsman Downtime is inevitable sometimes, unfortunately.

Comment: You meant /etc/rc6.d instead of /etc/r6.d?